# Find youtube channel name with channel id

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to get a youtube channels name if you have the channel id for that channel?

Will i need to do the whole oauth thing to get it? or is there an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

[Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) has an Id parameter combined with snippet returns the title of the channel.

> id    string The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the
>   YouTube channel ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved. In
>   a channel resource, the id property specifies the channel's YouTube
>   channel ID.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

**Note**: this is a public call to the api so you can do this with an API key and there is no need to use Oauth2.